# htaccess rewrite questions for modifying url structure and redirecting back

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ 
index.php?pageid=$1&pageid=$2&pageid=$3 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php? 
pageid=$1&pageid=$2 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?pageid=$1 [NC,L]
```

This makes the following happen:

When someone enters https://www.thegoodmarketer.co.uk/contact-us/ for example it loads the following page https://www.thegoodmarketer.co.uk/index.php?pageid=contact-us

What I want to achieve:

1. When someone enters https://www.thegoodmarketer.co.uk/index.php?pageid=contact-us I want it to automatically redirect to the correct URL structure: https://www.thegoodmarketer.co.uk/contact-us/

The same applies to all pages.

I've tried so hard to understand htaccess but I cannot get my head around it!

Very grateful for any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below it is for one example of your url, and use end flag on internal redirect rule to prevent recursive redirecting.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageid=([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [QSD,R]

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$ index.php?pageid=$1 [NC,L,END]
```